# Outlook Add-In does not catch emails upon application startup - what hook should be implemented?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server

I have an **Outlook 2013** Add-In that handles emails upon arrival via the `NewEmailEx()` event handler.

This works great IF **Outlook** is running, but if it is not running, those emails do not get processed.

What event handler should I include within my `ThisAddIn_Startup()` so I can run the "unprocessed" emails that are new/unread in my Inbox upon starting **Outlook**?

Comment: This might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869202.aspx

Comment: @Sarvesh: This does not work for cases when Outlook is shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder - it will fire when Outlook syncs the mailbox with the server and the new messages are downloaded to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an event that's raised to indicate there are unread messages in your Inbox when Outlook starts. Or to be more actuate when your Add-ins starts.

But you can get a list of the Unread messages and process them when the StartUp event is raised.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MAPIFolder inbox =
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder
        (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Items unreadItems = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");

    foreach (var unreadItem in unreadItems)
    {
        // Process item

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(unreadItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the messages were already read (e.g. from a different machine or phone), they will be marked as read.